# How to change url path to ruby on rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create Ruby on Rails 3 application and have a question. I have created "Profile" controller that is accessible via following url - "/profile" - that is fine. After that I have added "Product" controller that is now accessible via "/products" url.

How to make Product's controller accessible via next url - "/profile/products" ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have added following code to my route.rb without any success

resources :profile do
  resources :products  
end

Where is a problem ? Also, I have no physical relationship between Profile and Product

Comment: The example you gave of "/profile/products" implies that Profile is a singular resource, and that it has_many Products. The code you added to your routes.rb will generate urls such as "/profile/1/products" instead.

Comment: my Profile has no model, just Controller and one View - the main purpose is to logically combine different links, such as Products and so on. This following code works - "scope "/profile" do resources :products end" and I can access for instance "/profile/products/4" but I still have an error when I trying to reach "/profile/products/"  How to make accessible the root url "/profile/products/" also ? Thanks

Comment: Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for ProfileController

Comment: This way I can access "/profile/products" but now have an error with simple "/profile" url - Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/profile" How to fix "/profile" ?

Comment: I have solved all problems "match "profile" => "profile#index". bdon, thanks a lot !